# UIView subview not resizing

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autoresize

I am working on a Universal Application. I have a View-based application which has one view controller.  I am adding a `UIImageView` as a subview.

My problem is that if I put the ImageView in `viewDidLoad`, it is getting resized in iPad.

But if I add the ImageView to view controller dynamically on button tap event, the `UIImageView` is not getting resized as per iPad.  Instead, it is showing ImageView with 320 x 480 dimensions.

Note: My View Controller has `setAutoresizesSubviews` to `YES`.

My code is as below:

```
-(void)buttonTap
{    
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"main-bg" ofType:@"png"]];
    UIImageView *imgViewMainBG = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
    imgViewMainBG.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    imgViewMainBG.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [self.view addSubview:imgViewMainBG];
    [imgViewMainBG release];
    [img release];
    img=nil;         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AutoresizingMask is for changing the size of all subviews according to the change in size of the superView whenever the superView's size is changed, it won't resize subviews at the time of adding a subView.

But you can find the bounds or frame of  self.view and set the frame property of imageView according to that bounds like below

```
 [imgViewMainBG setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,  
                                    self.view.frame.size.height)];
```

so that imgViewMainBG is fully visible in ipad

Comment: thanks for reply. but i cant use this, because i have other subviews for which size is not same as screen size. The other subviews have different sizes like (20,20,100,150). i want also these subviews to autoresize in ipad.

Comment: This has saved me so much grief, thanks for providing such a simple, straight forward solution!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing image view's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`.