# UIView do not autoresize subviews

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autoresize, subviews

hey my view does not resize my subviews (uibuttons) not correctly

***viewdidload***:

```
    UICheckbox *UICBox = [[UICheckbox alloc]init];
    [UICBox autoresizesSubviews];
    [UICBox setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];
    if (!i%2) {
        [UICBox setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - CheckboxSize.width/2 - distanceToMiddle,
                                   distanceToTop + j * CheckboxSize.height + distanceBetween,
                                   CheckboxSize.width,
                                   CheckboxSize.height)];
    }
    else{
        [UICBox setFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2 - CheckboxSize.width/2 + distanceToMiddle,
                                    distanceToTop + j * CheckboxSize.height + distanceBetween,
                                    CheckboxSize.width,
                                    CheckboxSize.height)];
        j++;
    }
```

after the call with

```
    sele = [[SelectionViewController alloc]init];
    [[sele view] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 300)];
```

there is no button anymore....

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248296/uiview-subview-not-resizing

Comment: this is another problem, for the fullscreen drawing it is good, but if i change the size there a no buttons visible

Comment: is it not possible to let resize the button automatically?